# Windows can't access external HDD, TestDisk can

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs, hard-drive-recovery

I have a WD 1TB external HDD (NTFS) that causes Windows Explorer to freeze up whenever I try to access it.

I had TestDisk analyze it and there seems to be nothing wrong: size is reported ok, partition table is fine, files are accessible. I had TestDisk write the partition table just to be sure, but nothing changed.

When I looked at the log, though, I saw that the "NTFS Volume is dirty." Could that be causing the problems? What should I try to gain normal access again?

Thanks, regards,

Miel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried **chkdsk** with /F attribute?

Open up Command Prompt (Run As Admin if you are using Win7) and type this:

```
chkdsk /F x:
```

where x: is your drive letter.. See if that fixes it.

Comment: I actually haven't tried that yet, because windows explorer keeps crashing when I try to do anything with the drive, so I was looking for non-microsoft solutions. But this may of course just work. I'll have a go after I've made a backup of the data using TestDisk.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Good thing I made a backup first, though, because I lost a lot of data in the restoration process.